# Android Studio building different flavor apk than selected one

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I am facing this strange issue on Android Studio installed on my Macbook Pro. I have two flavors (say FA and FB) in my project and two build types i.e. debug and release.

Issue : When I select FADebug from Build variants and then build apk through -
 Build >Build Apk, Android studio starts building FB flavor instead.

I am not facing this issue on my windows machine, though. Any inputs or help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Build -> Clean Project`. If is not fixed, try to `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: Tried will no luck.